# some css properties are not applied on netlify deployed website ( react js )

Tags: css, firebase, deployment, web-deployment, netlify

I deployed my website with the git hub method, but some css properties are not applied on the deployed website, like Google fonts, background color, items are not aligned correctly, etc. I tried to search on the web but couldn't find the solution. Please help me with this.

My netlify website link :- https://polite-blancmange-ccbff7.netlify.app/

this is deployed website
[image: this is deployed website]

github repository :- https://github.com/GJ747/gforce

this is on my local host

[image: local host]

please help me

Comment: please share the, github repo again

Comment: https://github.com/GJ747/gforce

Comment: i changed visibility setting you can check it now

Answer (score 0):

I posted this on the Netlify forum as well, and someone solved my problem.
check it on Netlify :- https://answers.netlify.com/t/some-css-properties-are-not-applied-on-the-website/72895

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.